# How sine wave is generated in wien bridge oscillator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, inverter, sine, wien-bridge

It is known that the initial feedback signal is developed from the noise in the resitors and the transients of the power supply. The question here is : why the waveform at the output is sine wave particulary and not any other waveform?

Comment: Because that's the solution of the equation describing the oscillator. Is there something specific you wanted to know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barkhausens oscillation condition is applicable for LINEAR systems (with feedback) only. This condition requires a loop gain of unity (magnitude of "1" and zero phase). For most of the frequency-dependent networks this phase condition can be fulfilled for one single frequency only. Hence, there is only **one single frequency**, which can lead to self-sustained oscillations. In case of the WIEN oscillator a simple RC bandpass is used providing a magnitude maximum and a phase of zero deg at the same frequency.

As mentioned, this applies to linear systems only. On the other hand, a safe start of oscillations needs a loop gain slighter larger than unity - with continuously rising amplitudes. In order to make sure that the amplitudes are not hard-limited (clipped) at the supply voltage rail, we use an amplitude-control mechanism to enable soft-limiting which can maintain the sinusoidal form of the signal.